# How to change colour of line chart according to the x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe

```
structure(list(dteday = c("2011-01", "2011-02", "2011-03", "2011-04", 
"2011-05", "2011-06", "2011-07", "2011-08", "2011-09", "2011-10", 
"2011-11", "2011-12", "2012-01", "2012-02", "2012-03", "2012-04", 
"2012-05", "2012-06", "2012-07", "2012-08", "2012-09", "2012-10", 
"2012-11", "2012-12"), cnt = c(38189L, 48215L, 63422L, 94870L, 
135821L, 143512L, 141341L, 136691L, 127418L, 123511L, 102167L, 
87323L, 96744L, 103137L, 164875L, 174224L, 195865L, 202830L, 
203607L, 214503L, 218573L, 198841L, 152664L, 123713L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And this is the current line graph I have

```
 ggplot(bike2, aes(x=dteday, y=cnt, group = 1))+
     geom_line(color = "green", size = 1.2) + 
     labs(title = "Bike Rentals Per Month",
          x = "Month/Year",
          y = "Count") + 
          theme_solarized() +
          theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
```

[image]

The x axis is according to month and year. What I want is for 2011 to be in yellow and then 2012 to be in green to differentiate the years better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exract the year data from the data and use it as `color` in `aes`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(transform(bike2, year = substr(dteday, 1, 4)), 
       aes(x=dteday, y=cnt, group = 1, color = year))+
  geom_line(size = 1.2) + 
  labs(title = "Bike Rentals Per Month",
       x = "Month/Year",
       y = "Count") + 
  #theme_solarized() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
```

If you want to give the years some specific color you can do that via `+ scale_color_manual(values = c('green', 'yellow'))`.